# Group by column and find the min and max date by group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data set:

```
Time        Title
00:00:00    Title #one
00:12:38    Title #one
00:13:39    Title #one
00:33:14    Title #one
00:33:44    Title #two
00:49:27    Title #two
00:49:57    Title #two
00:59:43    Title #two
00:59:51    Title #three
00:59:59    Title #three
01:28:29    Title #three
01:28:38    Title #four
01:29:08    Title #four
01:29:38    Title #four
01:29:59    Title #four
01:37:08    Title #four
01:37:53    Title #four
01:38:53    Title #four
01:46:20    Title #four
```

I want to be able to group by Title and returns the min and max time for each title.

I've been able to get the min and max time for each titles with this:

```
df_max = df.groupby(['Title'])['Start time'].max()
df_min = df.groupby(['Title'])['Start time'].min()
```

However I don't really understand what `df_max` and `df_min` are returning exactly and how I should merge them...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.agg` method.

```
df.groupby(['Title']).agg({'Start time':[min,max]})
```

Comment: What is the output of this?